# Customization of the donation receipt

Tags: wordpress

All,

How is it possible to customize the receipt following the payment of a donation?

I would like to add the logo of our association, customize the text and of course add an incremental receipt number

Tx for your support

SL

Answer (score 1):

You can customize receipt templates at Administer > Communications > Message Templates > System Workflow messages

You can find more information on [CiviCRM Documentation](https://civicrm.org/documentation) The guides are searchable.

Answer (score 1):

Should you have more complex workflows for donation receipts, you may want to take a look at the donation receipt extension which is documented here:
https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/DonationReceipts+Extension